# How can I post some data from google app script to my python script on the local machine?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, flask-socketio

I have a google spreadsheet and a google app script which allows me to get the user selected values on the sheet. I need to know a way which helps me to send me this user selection to my python script on the local machine so that I query my data storage file and return back the updated values to the google sheet.

1. I have tried using python [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) but this doesnt let me get the data selected by the user on the spreadsheet.
2. I have tried to use Socket.io to establish a connection between google script and flask server but havent been successful at it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the selected information and store it in a file and Google Drive Sync will copy it to your local drive where you could open it with Python.